# Apache redirect to SERVER_NAME

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

Sorry for noob question.

Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.

I'm seeing a lot of redirect answers that hard-code urls into them. I also saw an answer that includes Apache `macro` and variables.

I want a simple, domain-name-portable solution.

I tried this but I ended up in a redirect loop or a 404, depending on which address I went to:

```
#global ServerName
ServerName example.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName butkus.com
  ServerAlias www.butkus.com

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^%{SERVER_NAME} [nocase]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$          %{SERVER_NAME} [last,redirect=301]
  .
  .
  .
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure what the `%` does. I assumed it is necessary syntax there. The logic I'm attempting there is, if the requested host name does not match the `VirtualHost`'s `ServerName`, to redirect to `ServerName`.

Urls on the left should redirect to those on the right:

www.butkus.com -> butkus.com
www.butkus.com/widget/party -> butkus.com/widget/party

And if I swap the ServerName and ServerAlias values, I would like it to work in reverse.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's not a server related question? There are a million answers to this already? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that's missing is you need to add an http:// on the RewriteRule line.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://%{SERVER_NAME} [last,redirect=301]
```

If that doesn't do the trick, turn increase the logging using `LogLevel trace6` and then do a request and check out your Apache error log to see what it's trying to do.

As a tip, just use `redirect` instead of `redirect=301` when debugging so you don't have to deal with the browser caching redirects and wild goose chases that may lead you on.

Comment: I would actually need to match either `http` or `https` and keep it the same. So I might need to capture that somehow. `(http(s?))` or something like that? Then use `$1` for re-inserting it below?

Comment: Also, very good point about the 301's. They definitely were a bad idea to put in before this was working.

Comment: @ButtleButkus you can duplicate the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` pair of directives that you have currently then add a `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` before the first copy and for that `RewriteRule` have it redirect to https and for the other one just have it do http.